# Suggestions for best way of implementing HTTP upload resume

Tags: apache, http

I'm working on a project which will allow large files (GB+) to be uploaded via HTTP PUT and I need to implement a method for resuming the upload. Once a file is uploaded and finalized it is complete and cannot be modified. So far, I have 2 options in mind but neither of which fit perfectly:

**Option 1**

Client sends an initial HEAD request on the file which will return either 404 if it does not exist or the file details including current size along with an HTTP X-Header along the lines of `X-Can-Resume` or something like that to specify whether the file can be resumed and a `Range` header specifying which bytes it has. This seems OK but I'm not keen on the X-Header as it removes from the HTTP standard.

**Option 2**

Client sends a PUT request with a `Content-Length` header of 0 bytes and no body, the server can then send back a `308 Resume Incomplete` (as proposed here http://code.google.com/p/gears/wiki/ResumableHttpRequestsProposal) or a `202 Accepted` header to indicate whether to resume or start from the beginning. This also seems acceptable apart from the use of a non-standard header.

Any other suggestions on the best way to implement this?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 0):

In either solutions there is no existing client and server implementations, so I'm guessing you'll code both. I think you should just find a right balance between the simplest and what is described in the gears proposal (by the way, you probably know Gears is dead), and be prepared to change when a standard emerges.

If I were to implement this feature, I'd make it possible for the client to upload in chunks and I would add a message digest on the whole content and the chunks.

Comment: Yes, I will be coding both the client and the server implementation. I know Gears is dead but it's the closest thing I've found to a solution to the problem. I am using a signature to verify the data, I'm just not sure on the best way to initiate the transfer. I'm swaying towards option 2 at the moment but I'm still not convinced either way at this point.